# How to Sign one testing application in android source

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I am able to add one testing application and build it in android source. But the problem is that the new testing application is not getting signed with the platform key. I have added 
`LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform` in android.mk file. But still it is not getting signed properly. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this problem?